# Problem with Sectiontitle formatting

Tags: section-titles

I want to mark the CV in which the sections are in capitals (sc shape and underlined.
While overleave generates the correct output errors are reported. How to resolve this issue?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftitle={CV},pdfauthor={Fnu Snu}, pdfsubject={CV},pdfcreator={Overleaf},colorlinks=false,allbordercolors=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ydnt,style=apa,isbn=false,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\scshape}{}{}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{3pt plus 0pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\textbf}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{3pt plus 0pt}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\cvitem}[2]
    {\begin{itemize}[topsep=-3pt,align=left,labelwidth=100pt,labelsep=8.5pt,leftmargin=!]
        \item [{#1}]{#2}
    \end{itemize}}
%===
%Content
%===
\begin{document}
\title{\vspace{-1.5cm}\textbf{Fnu Snu}}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-10ex}}
\maketitle
\noindent Short bio / description
\section{Personal Data}
    \cvitem{Date of birth}{01 January 1980}
    \cvitem{Nationality}{XY}
\end{document}
```

[image: Error report overleave]
[image: Correct output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the line

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\scshape}{}{}{}[\titlerule]
```

The fifth argument should be a length. From the documentation: *"[it] is the horizontal separation between label and title body and must be a length (it must not be empty)"*.  If it is supposed to be empty, use `0pt`.

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\scshape}{}{0pt}{}[\titlerule]
```